# Sort list files by semester and year

Tags: r, date, sorting

I am trying to sort a list files in a directory, I used differents libraries but all gave me the same result, example:

```
    myFiles <- paste0("Archivo_", c(1:2),"S",rep(c(2010:2015), each=2), ".txt") 

     # install.packages ('gtools')
     library ('gtools')
     mixedsort(myFiles)

    sort(myFiles)

    # install.packages("naturalsort")
     library("naturalsort")

    naturalsort(myFiles)

     [1] "Archivo_1S2010.txt" "Archivo_1S2011.txt" "Archivo_1S2012.txt"
     [4] "Archivo_1S2013.txt" "Archivo_1S2014.txt" "Archivo_1S2015.txt"
     [7] "Archivo_2S2010.txt" "Archivo_2S2011.txt" "Archivo_2S2012.txt"
    [10] "Archivo_2S2013.txt" "Archivo_2S2014.txt" "Archivo_2S2015.txt"
```

I would like get

```
 myFiles

  "Archivo_1S2010.txt" "Archivo_2S2010.txt" "Archivo_1S2011.txt"  
      "Archivo_2S2011.txt" "Archivo_1S2012.txt" "Archivo_2S2012.txt"
      "Archivo_1S2013.txt"  "Archivo_2S2013.txt"  "Archivo_1S2014.txt" 
      "Archivo_2S2014.txt"  "Archivo_1S2015.txt"  "Archivo_2S2015.txt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  library(dplyr)
  myFiles %>% 
    tibble(archivo=.) %>% 
    mutate(archivo_ref = gsub("_\\dS", "", archivo)) %>% 
    arrange(archivo_ref) %>% 
    select(archivo) %>% 
    unlist %>% 
   unname
 [1] "Archivo_1S2010.txt" "Archivo_2S2010.txt" "Archivo_1S2011.txt" "Archivo_2S2011.txt"
 [5] "Archivo_1S2012.txt" "Archivo_2S2012.txt" "Archivo_1S2013.txt" "Archivo_2S2013.txt"
 [9] "Archivo_1S2014.txt" "Archivo_2S2014.txt" "Archivo_1S2015.txt" "Archivo_2S2015.txt"
```